# Only one tokenizer filter is added when creating/replacing a new field type

Tags: curl, solr, filter, tokenize, fieldtype

I'm adding my field type using Curl:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-type:application/json' --data-binary '{
    "add-field-type" :  {
        "name":"valueWithSubFields",
        "class":"solr.TextField",
        "positionIncrementGap":"100",
        "indexAnalyzer":{
            "tokenizer": { "class":"solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory" },
            "filters": [{ "class":"solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"}],
            "filters": [{ "class":"solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory" }],  
            "filters": [{ "class":"solr.ReversedWildcardFilterFactory" }]           
        },
        "queryAnalyzer": {
            "tokenizer": { "class":"solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory" },
            "filters": [{ "class":"solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" }],
            "filters": [{ "class":"solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory" }]
        }
    }
}' http://localhost:8983/solr/myMainCore/schema
```

here's my created field type

```
<fieldType name="valueWithSubFields" class="solr.TextField"  positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.ReversedWildcardFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

The problem is that only the last tokenizer filters are actually added. I don't really get why this is happening. I tried to change my tokenizer class but still get the same result.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array of filters should be this way

```
"filters": [
              {
                 "class":"solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"
              },
              {
                 "class":"solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"
              },
              {
                 "class":"solr.ReversedWildcardFilterFactory"
              }
          ],
```

and the full curl command would be

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-type:application/json' --data-binary '{
    "add-field-type" :  {
        "name":"valueWithSubFields",
        "class":"solr.TextField",
        "positionIncrementGap":"100",
        "indexAnalyzer":{
            "tokenizer": { "class":"solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory" },
            "filters": [
                    {
                        "class":"solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"
                    },
                    {
                        "class":"solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"
                    },
                    {
                        "class":"solr.ReversedWildcardFilterFactory"
                    }
                ]           
        },
        "queryAnalyzer": {
            "tokenizer": { "class":"solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory" },
            "filters": [
                    {
                        "class":"solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"
                    },
                    {
                        "class":"solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"
                    }
                ]
        }
    }
}' http://localhost:8983/solr/myMainCore/schema
```